# Typescript scope in generic functions cannot be narrowed as expected

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

## Typescript scope in generic functions cannot be narrowed as expected

I have an `EventType` enum, and the relations between `EventType` and its corresponding params.

```js
enum EventType { A, B };

interface EventParams {
    [EventType.A]: { name: string, age: number }
    [EventType.B]: { address: string }
}
```

But when I use these definitions in generic functions and clarify the value of `EventType` through a `if` scope, the `param` is not narrowed down to the corresponding type in `EventParams`:

```js
const run1 = function <T extends EventType>(eventName: T, param: EventParams[T]) {
    if (eventName === EventType.A) {
        // ts error here
        param.name
    }
}
```

It still looks like a collection of all the values in `EventParams`:

[image]

And this is another related question: When I created processing callback for each `EventType`:

```js
type EventCallbacks = {
    [EventName in EventType]: (param: EventParams[EventName]) => any
}

const callbacks: EventCallbacks = {
    [EventType.A]: param => {},
    [EventType.B]: param => {}
}
```

And use these in generic functions, The type of `callback` is still not narrowed to the corresponding `T` generic:

```js
const run2 = function <T extends EventType>(eventName: T, param: EventParams[T]) {
    const callback = callbacks[eventName];
    // ts error here
    callback(param);
}
```

[image]

Here is the complete example in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAogbqALgFQJ4AdhQN5QIIA0UAQlAL4DcAsAFC0CWIiwATgGYCGAxlvEgAocWHCAGcctKFKgBtPkzSYAdHgC6ALhxQQI4JtGIWjAOZEOxvdsgAjVuUnS5CBRmBLiGrRwAm3lsFFRfUMTexoyWlouAHsQAygWMBAARigAXig2JK5EelioAB5kKGAAD2YQb3F5FFcAPgAKYGdEADldTWQidCERTRrBYTEZZFUASgkaaSh6NigmlvaILDTV2BbFNzwJ7AdpqR6hpR1lvbCIuhpEV3WkAGEOABtH624Aa3EM3anHGqWsRi3FyYTwNQ59IGIQYiUROJD-cbpOpQDggVC0C5RWLxLhPF7vIKQh7PV5cD7pSbTOHAraecHQNLI7BkAhnam1ZQeTT0pE4C6YmgxOKIBJJABMFKyIByeRAhWKZQqVUhm0azXhHSgXSg9P6LWhw1GOzOQpxeNJbwpuJJBJk6qYCOoPyk1vxZLBvQgYydAqAA).

So is there something wrong with my code or typescript can't handle this type of narrowing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine this scenario

```
run1<EventType.A | EventType.B>(EventType.A, {address: 'foo'})
```

This is perfectly valid code. If `T` extends `EventType`, it doesn't mean that `T` is one of `EventType`, it could totally be a union. In this case you could pass `EventType.B` to `eventName` and an object for `EventType.A` to `param`, which would cause problems at runtime. So you can't do it this way. One option is using a type guard, although I think it is nicer to use a discriminated union like this:

```
const run1 = function<T extends EventType>(
    data: T extends any ? {eventName: T, param: EventParams[T]} : never
) {
    if (data.eventName === EventType.A) {
        // no ts error here
        data.param.name
    }
}
```

Now if `T` is `EventType.A | EventType.B`, `data` will be of type

```
| {eventName: EventType.A, param: EventParams[EventType.A]} 
| {eventName: EventType.B, param: EventParams[EventType.B]}
```

And typescript is able to infer everything. <strike>Make sure you don't desctructure the arguments (don't do `const {eventName, param} = data`) because the connection in the discriminated union is lost, when you do the destructuring. Normally you could destructure the variables inside the `if` statement, after type narrowing has taken place, but in this situation ts gets a bit confused and doesn't work as expected, probably because of the generic.</strike> UPD: in late TS 4.x versions you can destructure this object and still get valid types.

Also you need this `T extends any` thing so that if `T` is a union, a separate object is created for every member of the union. If you omit it, you will just get `{eventName: EventType, param: EventParams[EventType]}` which is no good.

Actually going this way you don't really need the generic in the first place, you could just create a discriminated union for all combinations of event/param pairs like this

```
const run2 = function(
    data: {
        [key in EventType]: {eventName: key, param: EventParams[key]}
    }[EventType]
) {
    if (data.eventName === EventType.A) {
        // Now typescript doesn't get confused when destructuring
        const {eventName, param} = data
        param.name
    }
}
```

Same thing with callbacks, if `T` is a union, typescript isn't able to infer the correct type. This is also solved using discriminated unions, see [Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/KYOwrgtgBAogbqALgFQJ4AdhQN5QIIA0UAQlAL4DcAsAFC0CWIiwATgGYCGAxlvEgAocWHCAGcctKFKgBtPkzSYAdHgC6ALhxQQI4JtGIWjAOZEOxvdsgAjVuUnS5CBRmBLiGrRwAm3lsFFRfUMTexoyWlpEV1hnRABhDgAbJOtuAGtxAF4JGmlZeUQAOV0oRlikRWBPAAp0IRFNQsFhMSckEohqgEooLIA+KA4QVFoImi4AexADKC5k1IygiqZElLSuTL7c-PaXZTVNeta+wewyAgcpPZRXd09jkVOccfHaKZnEKBYwEABGbZsX5cRD0aYAHmQUGAAA9mCBvOJClV+jUrlBvBxEBxNFDYfDEUMRlAAPw4YBxTqWZBER4QJpxFoiUQyZCqMhQTQgCmsWi9bDo+hsKA1THYpQ8phUvpZHLIu54fno-IAehV2kmUEQ4lYLEmLCgAAtWMBldIxRwlHSlDoumapPa5tNZvN1hltq7FpsWRaJZTdKpHZ6NulRVjLXTuujXpEaD9-uD5QdUdhJcVdAzKgraQ16ThbZYAOQcQtmCyaABMZDIUbjvz+ibiVRUKbTVMz+zchCgdM02B8fgCy0LbEmk0L1d6auhMMwIOA3mhLD1LFo8YbSbcxFb-q6HduymIOdafYLmmLpaG5agVZrUGnsLnzEXuv1a-rjazh53HQzKwPW7Ho0OADv4gTnqO46TrG66fp2P5Sn+m4qEBebYGeUAXmWli3rWsGbgh6Z7v+zbdr2IG+GBw6QROd4PrOwDzi+y5vnWCYETUqa7pYyFHj2uann+WFXjhk73uqj6Mc+S4ru+7FNq4hHtiRdx8eR-aUUOEFjrRtbvM6XzxhWgLAqC0xonk5rhn2joyOkwCoGUIAqZgnhcb+xH2agqH7kybReey0Y3FUgY0EqllSEKIq+m2pSynKCkHOF+T5B8szuYhXSoRyOQWo604gJq2oyfqRomo61oFrGKXSGlXzBu6OQNd6MixV0oU1VIzWhpG0ZjLGckVpxbU8YlXY+fmQklthlbQWxQ0ZURo1fuN-EnhRg7gZhNFifRT4LiVq7zcN3H7s2akCZNxHCeYol0RJDFMYdg0nR5y2du4E0aZt1E6XNQA). However if you just want to do `const callback = callbacks[eventName]` without checking `eventName` type, it's a bit more complicated, you probably will need some type casts.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript would not be able to tell the type of `params` just with the check on `eventName === EventType.A` as you can always pass it as EventType.B but still send the params in the shape of `{ address: 'some address' }`

You must control that to make sure it's of the right type.

My suggestion is to go with something like this,

```
const isOfTypeA = (params: EventParams[EventType]): params is EventParams[EventType.A] => {
    if('name' in params && 'age' in params){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

const run1 = function <T extends EventType>(param: EventParams[T]) {
    if(isOfTypeA(param)){
        console.log(param.age);
    }
}

run1({ name: 'sample name', age: 123});
```

Comment: thanks! I've thought about it, but there are more enum items than this example. I'm not very inclined to add type judgment function for each enum item. @Alex Chasin 's answer has made me understand the reason for this issue. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

**@Alex Chasin 's answer IMHO is  correct**. My answer is just small extension.
If you don't want to change structure of function's arguments, you can use tuple instead:

```js
enum EventType { A, B };

interface EventParams {
    [EventType.A]: { name: string, age: number }
    [EventType.B]: { address: string }
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Params = Values<{
    [Prop in EventType]: [eventName: Prop, param: EventParams[Prop]]
}>

const foo = (...params: Params) => {
    if (params[0] === EventType.A) {
        // ts error here
        params[1].name // string
    }
    if (params[0] === EventType.B) {
        // ts error here
        params[1].address // string
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-dev.20210905#code/KYOwrgtgBAogbqALgFQJ4AdhQN5QIIA0UAQlAL4DcAUFQJYiLABOAZgIYDGW8SACm0zYQAzjipQJUANo8GaTADo8AXQBcOKCCHB1wxE3oBzIm0M7NkAEbNy4yTIRyMwBcTUa2AE09Ngw4br6RrZkNIjOUABqbAA2YH4APMgAfFAAvFDIUgDWwKgA9iyZymER-IIi6VGx8cIJ2HYSUrxM%20ehQ9LCOKM7uUsDdAHLa6i1tROgCQuqyiOVCws2t6MolZMk0HPkgelAs%20flVABQKp5MVAVDzIgCU6akNkh1FR%20cLUgAMyulpGbPyLjwd0eT0kAHowVBEKJmK0mFAABbMYCNUFvERSACMygUWggWAhUD0BhAhlRoSetBe6MWXx%20f26ANcwNRT0J0KgsPy8KRvlZkhpWJxXh8flEhOJRnJVDIQA)

Comment: Ingenious solution! I have never thought about it before. Thank you for your answer!